# Plugins/modules shared by multiple programs

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, plugins

I want to define plugin like objects for my program. They should look like this:

```
class ModuleBase
{
public :
   void baseFunction1();
   void baseFunction2();
   ...   
   virtual void init() = 0;
   virtual void finalize() = 0;
};

class SpecificModule : public ModuleBase
{
public :
   virtual void doSpecificTask() = 0;
};
```

Thus I will have SpecificModule implementations:

```
class ConcreteSpecificModule1 : public SpecificModule
{
public :
   void init();
   void finalize();
   void doSpecificTask();
};
```

In order to mask implementation and complexity, I want my modules to see the underlying system through a facade Interface :

```
class SystemViewForSpecificModule
{
public :
   virtual SystemData& getData(//some parameters) = 0;
   virtual void doSystemAction1() = 0;
   virtual void doSystemAction2() = 0;
   ...
};
```

Finally I want to be able to make several programs that can deal with Module and / or `SpecificModule` instances.

Considering I have prog1, prog2, and prog3, I will have to implement
`Prog1View`, `Prog2View` and `Prog3View` as concrete implementations of `SystemViewForSpecificModule` interface.

Additionally, I have to consider the following case :

**Prog2 will embed Prog1** and I want to be able to do this :

1. instantiate the `SpecificModule` instances
2. run the prog1 part that make calls to `SpecificModule::doSpecificTask();`
3. run the prog2 part that also call `SpecificModule::doSpecificTask();`

**My question is:** How to pass / store the reference (or pointer) to the system in the SpecificModule instances ?

**1 - Storing the reference at construction time :**

thus the SpecificModule interface should like

```
class SpecificModule : public ModuleBase
{
   SystemViewForSpecificModule& m_sys;
public :
   SpecificModule(SystemViewForSpecificModule& sys):m_sys(sys){}
   virtual void doSpecificTask() = 0;
};
```

This is a pleasant way to achieve my problem, but don't forget that in prog2 I have first to
run my modules with prog1, thus I have to switch from SystemViewForSpecificModule implementation dynamically in this case.

- (+) Modules can access  to system during their whole life and all method can get access to it.
- (-) Once the reference set, it can not be changed

We can consider that using a reference is not a good solution, or use something like this:

```
class SystemView : public SystemViewForSpecificModule
{
    SystemViewForSpecificModule* concreteSystem; 
public
    SystemView(SystemViewForSpecificModule& sys)
    {concreteSystem = &sys;}

    void setSystem(SystemViewForSpecificModule& sys)
    {concreteSystem = &sys;}

    void doSystemAction1()
    {concreteSystem->doSystemAction1();}
    ...
}
```

This way, the module doesn't even know that the implementation has changed
However, I'm afraid it will reduce performance due to extra vtable access.

**2 - Using a setter to specify the system view**

The SpecificModule interface should like:

```
class SpecificModule : public ModuleBase
{
   SystemViewForSpecificModule* m_sys;
public :
   setSystem(SystemViewForSpecificModule& sys){m_sys = &sys;}
   virtual void doSpecificTask() = 0;
};
```

That seems to be a convenient solution but I don't like the fact that the module has:

- the knowing of this change
- to handle this change
- to check the validity of the pointer before using it

**3 - Passing references to SpecificModule methods**

At least the `SpecificModule` interface will look like that:

```
class SpecificModule : public ModuleBase
{
   virtual void doSpecificTask(SystemViewForSpecificModule& sys) = 0;
};
```

I don't like to pass the same reference 10000 times to the same function (both prog1 and prog2 part will call it lot of times).

Another bad point for this solution is: I don't have access to the system view in the `ModuleBase` methods (such as `init()` and `finalize()`). And obviously, moving them to the subclasses would reduce the inheritance interest.

What solution would you use in this example case (I hope to see other solutions than the 3 presented)?

Comment: Can you please explain me why this is a bad question, I tried to make it as clear as possible

Comment: Suggestion: Pass a `std::vector<std::string>` to the virtual functions.  You might later want to pass arguments to some module interfaces, and this is a pretty general way to make that possible.

Comment: @aschepler : I have already a `setCustomParameter(const std::string& param, const std::string& value);` in my `ModuleBase` class. But my problem is how to make modules get access to the system that runs them?